# How do I acquire the pagekey I put in header location?

Tags: php, mysql, header

I have a header redirect that's `header("Location: http://mywebsite.com/folder/PAGEKEY");`
Where `PAGEKEY` is a random generated key that looks like this: `z4k4IKCL`.

My questions is how can I acquire the key from the address? I need to be able to link to the URL and can't rely on information used on the previous page.

the key will be used to query a MYSQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url =$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

$parts = explode("/", $url);

$pagekey = $parts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

This gives you everything on the url after the `http://mywebsite.com` part of the url.